# How to write a constructor for a class?

Tags: java, constructor

I have been given a class declaration and I am trying to write the constructor of the Pet class.

```
class Pet {
  protected String name;
  protected boolean indoor;
  ...
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public boolean getIndoor() { return indoor; }
  }
class Goat extends Pet{
  public int age;
  public String diet;
  public Goat(String name, boolean indoor, int age, String diet) {
    super(name, indoor);
    this.age = age;
    this.diet = diet;
  }
}
```

with the required test as:
[image]

This is what I wrote up so far, but got stuck on the way.

```
  class Pet {
  public String name;
  public boolean indoor;
  public Pet(String a, boolean b){
      name = a;
      indoor = b;
  }
}
```

This is the following errors I am getting when executed.
[image]

- **Updated code and error Message**

What would be a good step to get the code to work for the class?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Your task is to write a constructor. Why did you change the names and visibility  of the fields and removed the getters? They were right from the start

Comment: Your constructor looks fine, but you invented two new fields that are not necessary and left out the stuff from the original class template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the instance variable names to match how you refer to them (actually, put stuff back the way it was before):

```
class Pet {
  protected String name;
  protected boolean indoor;
  public Pet(String a, boolean b){
      name = a;  // <-- assigns the argument to the instance variable
      indoor = b;
  }

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public boolean getIndoor() { return indoor; }
}
```

When you see a name prefixed with get that is an accessor (or getter), those are the getName and getIndoor methods. The getter is only for accessing, not changing, so `getName = a` doesn't work.

Comment: so I tried changing the code as you have stated, but I'm getting a different error.

Answer (score 0):

Your Pet class Constructor should be like below:

```
 class Pet {
      private String name;
      private boolean indoor;
      public Pet(String name, boolean indoor){
          this.name = name;  
          this.indoor = indoor;
      }

      public String getName() { return name; }
      public boolean getIndoor() { return indoor; }
    }
```